# SVN merge to different file?

Tags: svn

Say I made a copy of file A as file B in SVN repository and made some changes to file B. Then someone changed file A, and I want to bring in those changes into file B, how can I do that? The directories were not copied by svn copy command because their names need to be different. They are copied locally, remove .svn directories, renamed from A to B, then svn add, then svn ci.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you  don't use the built-in Subversion tools for copying and moving, you can't expect Subversion to be able to track your changes. As far as Subversion is concerned, these are completely new files and have nothing to do with the old copies. There's no easy way to do a Subversion merge in this case.

You can do a [`svn --ignore-ancestry`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.ancestry), but that will only do merging of files with similar names, and it will end up doing a two-way merge which means that any differences in the files will be notified even if those changes took place on the branch itself. No history, no three-way merge.

The best you can do in your circumstance is to do a manual merge using some diffing tool.

**Do not ever copy files from one part of the repository to another without doing a `svn cp`. You've basically broke your ability to use Subversion to maintain your merges.**

The next time you do something like this, do a `svn cp` to copy the files elsewhere, commit the changes, and then do a `svn mv` to rename or move files around. This allows Subversion to track the file renames and moves.